# How can I put a href property on a carousel item in Vuetify 2?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js, carousel

I am working with Vuetify 2 and need to redirect the user to a website when he clicks on the image of the carousel, each item of the carousel should take to a different website, so it needs to have more than one href or something like that.

```html
<v-carousel>
  <v-carousel-item
    src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/R.1f617f6c0e62cf22f8cc0db2d56c9b28?rik=%2fsedPErWt7A%2bIA&riu=http%3a%2f%2f2.bp.blogspot.com%2f-rhsJGYj0RFc%2fUJ8G5i3UEHI%2fAAAAAAAAABg%2fQY0NlUG7lBI%2fs1600%2fwallpaper-praia-wallpapers%2b(13).jpg&ehk=AkwUJUusgP9ImnYhvxvSQ0PSTFbjvJlKlUSeikKT%2bAQ%3d&risl=&pid=ImgRaw&r=0"
    cover></v-carousel-item>

  <v-carousel-item src="https://th.bing.com/th/id/R.5fedcc584b436fe320057461d49f3996?rik=0iHP4CUZiAaMyQ&pid=ImgRaw&r=0" cover></v-carousel-item>

  <v-carousel-item src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/cards/sunshine.jpg" cover></v-carousel-item>
</v-carousel>
```

I've tried some of the props available in the API, but I don't know if I wrote it correctly or it doesn't work in Vuetify 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap each v-carousel-item with an `<a>` tag.

```html
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/" target="_blank">
  <v-carousel-item />
</a>
```